# Determining distance between two point locations specified in degrees, minutes and decimal seconds?

Tags: distance

Without using GIS software, how can I determine how far it is from 20°01'12.07" N -75°47'53.57" W to 20°01'15.28" N -75°47'46.02" W, which are two point locations (historical battles) specified in degrees, minutes and decimal seconds?

- Point A: 20:01:12.07N; 75:47:53.57W
- Point B: 20:01:15.28N; 75:47:46.02W

Comment: What GIS software are you using?  What projected coordinate system do you wish to use to perform that calculation? GIS SE does not provide a distance calculation service.

Comment: @PolyGeo It's more of an in general question.

Comment: You could try using a search like this to find a distance calculation service: https://www.google.com/search?q=distance+calculation+using+degrees+minutes+seconds

Comment: The real answer is complex, but if you just want an approximation, a nautical mile is one subtended minute, so convert degrees and seconds to minutes, find the difference, then substitute nautical miles for units, use the Pythagorean Theorem, then convert to meters or miles. If you want to be fancy, you can apply a cosine of the *degrees* latitude to the delta longitude before squaring it.